# move encrypted drive from one computer to another

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I just bought a new computer that also has M.2 drive slots in it.  I want to remove the disk from my old HP and move to the new thinkpad.  It looks like it will work except that once I enter my encrypted password it comes back and says it doesn't recognize the computer.  Like the encryption is based on the chipset of the original computer.

So the question is:  Can I decrypt to move it or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks,

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 18 and I used full disk encryption on the original drive.

Comment: I haven't heard of any full disk encryption on Ubuntu that uses some sort of chipset of the computer. Before booting starts please press Esc a few times or hold down left Shift, when in the menu select to start the computer in recovery mode. If it doesn't start, please post here the last error messages that you get by editing your original question.